# Any Microsoft exam is planned for SharePoint admin/developers?

Tags: exams, exam

Beside 70-339 which is going to be retired soon, there is no SharePoint exam available. I cannot find any exam for SP2019 or SP online. Is Microsoft in the middle of planning or SharePoint administrator no longer require qualification? Any Microsoft exam is planned for SharePoint admin/developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Developers**:

Currently there are no dedicated Microsoft certifications available for SharePoint development. Also, no certifications are planned in near future (as per my knowledge).

For developers, I will recommend to look at the [MS-600](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/MS-600) exam.

---

**For Administration**

There are multiple certifications available related to Microsoft/Office 365 which are mostly inclined to administration side like configuring and managing services and products, like:

- MS-900
- MS-100
- MS-101
- MS-203
- MS-500
- MS-700

Check complete list of exams at: [Microsoft 365 certification exams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/browse/?resource_type=examination&products=m365)

Below are some of the SharePoint certifications currently available:

1. [Managing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-339.aspx).

Comment: hmm, not sure why Microsoft still show the retired exam in the list. Only 3 out of 19 exams are still valid.

Comment: MS-900, MS-100, MS-101, MS-203, MS-500, MS-600, MS-700 are still valid. some of the exams are retired and some will retire soon (as you already know).

Comment: Could you add above list into the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Added.. Also, these are already enlisted in above "Microsoft 365 certification exams" link.